# installing mod_pagespeed on ubuntu22

Tags: 22.04, apache2, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to install `mod_pagespeed` on my AWS EC2 ubuntu-22 machine.

I am trying the following way

1. Download the stable release

   sudo wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb
2. Installing the package

   sudo dpkg -i mod-pagespeed-*.deb

Installation giving me the below error

> Selecting previously unselected package mod-pagespeed-stable:amd64.
> (Reading database ... 165032 files and directories currently
> installed.) Preparing to unpack mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb
> ... Unpacking mod-pagespeed-stable:amd64 (1.13.35.2-r0) ... dpkg:
> dependency problems prevent configuration of
> mod-pagespeed-stable:amd64:  mod-pagespeed-stable:amd64 depends on
> libc6 (>= 2.17).  mod-pagespeed-stable:amd64 depends on apache2.
>
> dpkg: error processing package mod-pagespeed-stable:amd64 (--install):
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
> while processing:  mod-pagespeed-stable:amd64

So I tried to install `libc6` by
`sudo apt-get install libc6` and getting below output

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading
> state information... Done libc6 is already the newest version
> (2.35-0ubuntu3.1). libc6 set to manually installed. 0 upgraded, 0
> newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.

It mean I already have the latest version of `libc` so why I am getting this error.

Comment: Silly question, but which EC2 instance type are you using?

Comment: @matigo type has anything to do with it?

Comment: If you're using one that doesn't support `amd64`, then yes. Hence the silly question: start with the easy stuff then begin digging into the more complicated things ...

Comment: architecture is `arm64` so I have added that architecture as foreign by `sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64`

Comment: Looks like [Google has no plans on supporting Arm](https://github.com/apache/incubator-pagespeed-ngx/issues/1213). That said, there is a comment near the bottom of that thread where someone offers a link that shows how to compile from source in order to make it work. This is outside the scope of something that I'm willing to test ahead of time, though.

Comment: @urfusion even adding AMD64 as foreign won't allow you to *run* it.  You won't be able to run this in arm64 environments.

Comment: Is there any way achieve this. Or a better caching mod of apache ?

Answer (score 0):

`mod_pagespeed` is an AMD64 package.  [Google has no intention on supporting ARM as a supported arch](https://github.com/apache/incubator-pagespeed-ngx/issues/1213) for pagespeed or other Google built plugins.

Even adding `amd64` as a foreign architecture won't solve your problem - you cannot run `amd64` code on an ARM processor (even `arm64`) as they don't speak the same languages.

You will NOT be able to install Pagespeed modules into Apache or otherwise if you are not using an `amd64` AWS EC2 instance.  Asa you are using an `arm64` instance, you cannot use Pagespeed.

Comment: Which AES EC2 you recommend to use for mod_pagespeed. Right now I am using `On Demand Linux t4g.xlarge`. Or best caching for ARM64 with apache2